# How can I include multiple text fields in a single NFC record?

Tags: nfc

I have copied someone there code for an NFC reader and writer to help myself for furture development on my app. I wanted to change the input from 1 textview to 4 textview's and thought I could do it myself but I am 4 days further and I still haven't found an method to do so.

Therefor I am asking here in the hope someone will help me.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edit_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    nfc_contents = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nfc_contents);
    ActivateButton =  findViewById(R.id.ActivateButton);
    context = this;
    Test1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Test1);
    Voorbeeld = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Voorbeeld);



    ActivateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(myTag ==null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, Error_Detected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    write(edit_message.getText().toString(), myTag);
                    Toast.makeText(context, Write_Success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Write_Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, Write_Error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if(nfcAdapter == null){
        Toast.makeText(this, "This device does not support NFC", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
    readFromIntent(getIntent());
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, 
    getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    writingTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };
}

private void readFromIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
            || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage[] msgs = null;
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        }
        buildTagViews(msgs);
    }
}

 private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
    if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

    String text = "";
    byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
    String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16"; // Get the Text Encoding
    int languageCodeLength = payload[0] & 51; // Get the Language Code, e.g. "en"

    try {
        
        text = new String(payload, languageCodeLength + 1, payload.length - languageCodeLength - 1, 
        textEncoding);


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e.toString());
    }

    nfc_contents.setText("NFC Content: " + text);

}



private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {
    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
    NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
    
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
   
    ndef.connect();
    
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
    
    ndef.close();
}

private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String lang       = "en";
    byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int    langLength = langBytes.length;
    int    textLength = textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

  
    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

    
    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

    return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    readFromIntent(intent);
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        myTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

    }
}
```

Comment: A question should have a [mre] with the shortest code that produces a _specific error_ when run without changes -- that error message should be included in the question itself, and should be more specific than just "goes wrong".

Comment: Including the specific exception or error in your code also ensures that other people with the same problem can find your question and learn from its answers, by making it more likely to come up when they search for that error. (If there _is_ no exception, again, describe that _as part of the question itself_)

Comment: ...if your question is, say, "how can I include multiple text fields in a single NFC record?", make that your title; it's asking a specific question, not just saying something "goes wrong".

Answer (score 1):

An NdefMessage can have multiple NdefRecords in it, therefore store each String from the 4 Texview's in to there own NdefRecord

e.g. change

```java
private void write(String[] textArray, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {

    NdefRecord[] records = new NdefRecord[textArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
        records[i] = createRecord(textArray[i]);
    }
    // Rest of code
```

Then you would call your `write` method like to pass it 4 Strings

```java
write(new String[] {
   edit_message1.getText().toString(),
   edit_message2.getText().toString(),
   edit_message3.getText().toString(),
   edit_message4.getText().toString()
   }, myTag);
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the help but I mind sound like a complete idiot but everywhere i put the write method to pass te 4 strings i get error

Comment: What is the error? I've noticed an extra ` appeared in my formatting of the `write` call, now fixed.

Comment: I have got 1 error in the onclick, it is asking me to delete the IOException e and the FormatException e. and I have got another error in the createRecord there is a line with Byte[] textbytes = text.getBytes(); that gives also an error that I cant seem to fix

Comment: Question do you really need this to work for before API level 21, if not it would be better to use the API call https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord#createTextRecord(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) instead of trying to program your own. I assume all the other code was working as this is not really about storing 4 strings instead of 1